# Table out multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I hope someone can help me, so I am querying an api and this is the response -

```
{
"data": {
    "today": [
        {
            "airdate": "2016-03-11", 
            "airs": "Daily 09:25", 
            "data_network": "cbeebies", 
            "data_show_name": "twirlywoos", 
            "ep_name": "Smaller", 
            "ep_plot": "The Twirlywoos pursue a very small butterfly at a butterfly farm.", 
            "episode": 25, 
            "indexerid": 292140, 
            "network": "CBeebies", 
            "parsed_datetime": "2016-03-11, 09:25 +0000", 
            "paused": 0, 
            "quality": "SD", 
            "season": 2, 
            "show_name": "Twirlywoos", 
            "show_status": "Continuing", 
            "tvdbid": 292140, 
            "weekday": 5
        }, 
        {
            "airdate": "2016-03-11", 
            "airs": "Friday 8:30 PM", 
            "data_network": "disney channel", 
            "data_show_name": "girl meets world", 
            "ep_name": "Girl Meets Legacy", 
            "ep_plot": "With middle school graduation around the corner, Riley, Maya, Lucas and Farkle work together to determine what kind of legacy they want to leave at John Quincy Adams.", 
            "episode": 30, 
            "indexerid": 267777, 
            "network": "Disney Channel", 
            "parsed_datetime": "2016-03-11, 20:30 -0500", 
            "paused": 0, 
            "quality": "SD", 
            "season": 2, 
            "show_name": "Girl Meets World", 
            "show_status": "Continuing", 
            "tvdbid": 267777, 
            "weekday": 5
}
      ]
  }, 
  "message": "", 
"result": "success"
}
```

I am trying to take each of the "data_show_name" values and output them in a table, I am doing this in PHP and I have been able to work out how to pick a single value -

```
echo $Sick["data"]["today"][1]["data_show_name"];
```

And this will print Girl Meets World, but I want to have a, by preference bullet pointed list, of all the of items that are returned on the call, and I can't quite work out how to do it, I guess its a ForEach or a Loop, but I can't sus the code out, i'm sure someone here will take one look and fix it in seconds..

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `foreach($Sick['data']['today'] as $k=>$v){ echo $v['data_show_name']; }`

Comment: Hey Kyle, that appears to be printing the first character of each show name, so the output (I have more in the real api call) was this - "tgibbbbbbbbbbt" and looking it is, its just the first letter from each show all in one word? this I pretty much what I had managed to accomplish already, but isn't right :(

Comment: use this instead:`as $v`. dont do the `$k=>$v` my bad. So: `foreach($Sick['data']['today'] as $v){ echo $v['data_show_name']; }`

Comment: foreach($Sick['data']['today'] as $v){ echo $v['data_show_name']['....']; } - still seems to give me the same "tgibbbbbbbbbbt" sorry being a pain mate..thanks for helping me out

Comment: without the `['....']` lol, I took that out cos I only scan read your Array. Just do this: `foreach($Sick['data']['today'] as $v){ echo $v['data_show_name']; }`

Comment: Ah ok, that worked, now how would i format that to a bullet pointed list? or at least put them on a new line? Thanks

Comment: Ill answer it in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already decoded the JSON to the $Sick Array:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($Sick['data']['today'] as $item) : ?>
    <li><?php echo $item['data_show_name'] ?></li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

also, if you have more *days* in your `data` object, you could iterate it, to...

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($Sick['data'] as $day) : ?>
    <?php foreach($day as $item) : ?>
        <li><?php echo $item['data_show_name'] ?></li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To get your details out you can use:

```
foreach($Sick['data']['today'] as $v){ echo $v['data_show_name']; }
```

To bullet point them you can use conditional statements:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($Sick['data']['today'] as $v): ?>
    <li> <?php echo $v['data_show_name']; ?> </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Conditional statements allow you to combine HTML and PHP together.